# Bokeh opens in new tab but no plot

Tags: python, google-chrome, bokeh

Trouble shooting video will help you analyze (problem solved Mar 24 2020: video deleted):
https://youtu.be/rh84QYYbFto

Problem:  Python opens bokeh in new tab, but no plot is shown.

Bokeh 2.0.0, python 3.6.7, google chrome
The code I used is directly from here:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/geo.html

Comment: Is there any output in the browser JavaScript console? It's possible you are running in to https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9773 in which case you will need to clear cache and/or force reload (just once)

Comment: Thank you, the solution to my problem was to clear settings (cache, cookies, etc.) in my browser.

Comment: Great! Can you answer an self-accept so that the question has an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to clear settings (cache, cookies, etc.) in my browser.